# Detect date selection on an HTML5 calendar element, but not manually entered date

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I need to be able to run a JavaScript function when a user clicks on a date in an HTML5 calendar element. I tried using `onchange`, but it also fires when the user types in a date:

```
<input type="date" onchange="alert('fired');"/>
```

It seems the event doesn't fire until they type in a "complete" date, which is neat, but doesn't meet my needs.

Is there a way to only fire when the date was clicked on in the calendar? Or maybe fire in both scenarios but detect which type of action it was?

Answer (score 0):

I gather you want to disable keyboard input so user can only select valid dates by mouse.

You also want to detect clicks inside the calendar.

For that I have this updated demo of the answer:

Note how the click handler will have an empty string value for clicks on invalid dates.

[InputDatePreventKeyboard](http://jsfiddle.net/anaran/3fEeR/)

Please note that writing event handlers in HTML attributes is not recommended.

See
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Use_functions_instead_of_evaluating_snippets_of_code

Here is the updated code of the demo:

```
<input type="date"
    onchange="alert(window.event.type+' event handler for '+this.type+' noticed  \''+this.value+'\'');"
    onclick="alert(window.event.type+ ' event handler for '+this.type+ ' noticed  \''+this.value+'\'');"
    onkeydown="window.event.preventDefault();
alert(window.event.type+' event handler for '+this.type+' prevents keyboard input for value \''+this.value+'\'');"
    onkeypress="window.event.preventDefault();
alert(window.event.type+' event handler for '+this.type+' prevents keyboard input for value \''+this.value+'\'');"
    oninput="alert(window.event.type+' event handler for '+this.type+' noticed \''+this.value+'\'');" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be behaving the same as onchange.

Comment: Please elaborate.
What is your navigator.userAgent
What is the exact problem?
Have you tried an onchange listener in combination which calls event.preventDefault(); to intercept keyboard input?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will elaborate/clarify. I have a date input field with a button next to it to execute the search. What I would like is when a user types in a date, they would then click the search button (indicating they are done entering the date). If they click a date in the calendar, I need the search to execute immediately. Problem is, onchange and oninput both fire when the user types in the last part of a date. I need nothing to fire when they typed, only when they clicked a date.

Comment: Is user allowed to type date by keyboard (digits, arrow key nav)?

Clicking the search button (indicating they are done entering the date) should not do a search?

How do they click a date in the calendar? On the text components? on the popup calendar view?

You want to perform the search function when they click the date?

What is the search button doing then?

Have you tried onclick?